# Unable to retrieve data from asp gridview after postback during end_request handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

**Process:**

The user enters parameters and clicks a button, codebehind uses parameters within a sql procedure. A datatable is created with procedure results along with an array with the same results.  On post-back the array is used to populate a listbox with just city names. The datatable is used to populate a gridview with a city name, zip, population, lat, lng on each row.

```
For i = 0 To Cities.Count - 1
    ListBox.Items.Add(Cities.Item(i)(0))
Next
GridView.DataSource = FinderTable
GridView.DataBind()
```

After my update panels have been updated I call a Javascript EndRequestHandler() that contains an onClick listener for the listbox to retrieve the index of the city name being selected.

**EndRequestHandler():**

```
$('#<%= ListBox.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    var ListElement = document.getElementById('<%= ListBox.ClientID%>');
    var GridElement = document.getElementById('<%= GridView.ClientID%>');
    var Index = ListElement.selectedIndex;
    console.log("index: " + Index)
    Lat = GridElement.rows[Index].Cells[3].value;
    Lng = GridElement.rows[Index].Cells[4].value;
    console.log("lats & lngs: " + Lat + ' ' + Lng);
});
```

What I'd like to do is to get the lat and lng of the city being selected so I can move my googlemap to the selected location when the user selects a city name within the listview.

When I click on a city name I'm getting an index # in console but I can't get the GridView

**Firefox's Console Error:**

```
TypeError: GridElement.Rows[Index].Cells is undefined
```

I'm getting an index # so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

In the finished code, I'd like to be able to hide the whole gridview and only use the data from it.  From what I've been reading, it looks like I should set visibility to false after I bind it in the codebehind.

**Answer:**

Cells should be cells (lowercase) and .value should be .textContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your code that you are writing Cells (capital 'C'), if so needs to have small c as Javascript follows camel casing.